# Undergraduate research project ideas

Tags: quantum-mechanics, education

I want to work on interesting project on quantum mechanics using the knowledge I gained from studying thoroughly the standard texts(Shankar,Griffith's and had a semester long course up to the level of relativistic quantum mechanics).I aspire it to be of the level of an undergrad thesis if possible.

I am interested in perturbed systems.

If possible kindly guide me with some necessary reading work for the suggested topics.

Thesis work is not mandatory in my course.

Comment: The topic of such a project should be decided between you and your academic advisor. He/she will be much better informed about your interests and the level of your abilities than we are.